# Deserializing a Claims field to string returns additional characters

Tags: rust, escaping, serde-json

I need to deserialize the following payload, in particular the `aud` field from a JSON object:

```
claims: Claims { 
    aud: One("CBr3zBlrKBbwmxOAM1avZQ=="), // 24 len
    // ...
}
```

`claims::aud` is an `Aud` enum:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, PartialEq)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Aud {
    One(String),
    Many(Vec<String>),
}
```

When I attempt to get a `String` from `serde_json::to_string()` it returns  two additional characters, an opening and ending char.

```
use serde_json::Result;

fn aud_from_json(data: &claims::Aud) -> Result<String> {
    let v = serde_json::to_string(&data)?;
    Ok(v.to_owned())
}
```

```
let aud = aud_from_json(&token_data.claims.aud)?;
log::debug!("aud field: {:?}\t aud field len({})", &aud, &aud.len());
```

```
$ aud field: "\"CBr3zBlrKBbwmxOAM1avZQ==\""         aud field len(26)
```

It appears there may be trailing escape characters serialized into the string.
Is there a method that can return `aud` field returned as `String`, sanitized without extra characters?
e.g. `"CBr3zBlrKBbwmxOAM1avZQ=="`

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: You also have some poorly named functions which might be underlying some of your problems. For example, you have a function called `aud_from_json` which does not take JSON as an argument. Instead, it seems to **create** JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a situation where `serde_json::to_string()` was mistaken for an actual `to_string()` implementation, as opposed to a JSON string.

Extracting an inner member of an enum variant is better done by pattern-matching. Due to the OP's requirements, the last `aud` member of the `Vec` is the most important one

Final implementation ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8872f48d9277b534f82e07347b0c10fc)):

```
use std::io::Result;
use serde;
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, PartialEq)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Aud {
    One(String),
    Many(Vec<String>),
}

fn aud_from_json(data: &Aud) -> Result<String> {
    match data {
        Aud::One(audience) => Ok(audience.clone()),
        Aud::Many(audiences) => audiences
          .last()
          .ok_or(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "No audience found"))
          .map(|r| r.clone())
    }
}
```

Comment: His issue is about the "extra escape characters serialized in the string", which you don't address at all

Comment: Added a disclaimer, although I honestly don't see how that could be the issue. That is literally standard `Debug` behavior.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, thanks for the clarification.  I do need to parse the string without the quotes since I need to decrypt the `aud` field.  I may have to do some more digging on `Deserialize` trait as you have pointed out or parse them out manually.  I thought perhaps serde-json had a convenience method to handle this case, that I was unaware of.

Comment: @Alex I get the feeling you're using the wrong tool for the job. You're provided with the base64-encoded string provided in your question as an example, correct? Is this part of a JWT? If so, where and how is JSON involved?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld `aud` is being used as an encrypted audience server identifier that is injected to a token as base64.  This is just an added layer of obfuscation on top of Atlassian S2S authentication protocol specification.  I'd like to de-structure `aud` from a given token response and decrypt it's value as an inspect method.

Comment: The encrypt/decrypt methods are spawned through a thread.  Right now, I'm getting an error: `thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Base64Error(InvalidByte(0, 34))` which I presume is because of the Quote characters.

Comment: @Alex Okay. Let's go back to first principles. Do you already have your `Claims` object deserialized? If so, what does your thread expect? A `String`? JSON? If it's a `String`, what prevents you from skipping the JSON serialization altogether? The reason I think you may be using the wrong tool is because I'm missing the point of JSON-serializing "just" a string.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld  I'm sorry for the confusion.  I need to deserialize the aud to a String.  To add more context on the reason as to why I'm spawning a thread for this is because I'm using a thread-safe cell to protect a static string key which is used in the obfuscation of aud to AES-256 base64 encoding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200181/discussion-between-sebastien-renauld-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you said in reply to @SébastienRenauld's answer, you want to base-64 decode the string that's contained in an `Aud` instance. This can be achieved with:

```
let aud = Aud::One("CBr3zBlrKBbwmxOAM1avZQ==".to_string());
if let Aud::One(code) = aud {
    let decoded = base64::decode(&code).unwrap();
    log::debug!("Decoded: {:?}", decoded);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b73d4574cbb4510a84694180d2984a23)

Comment: Not exactly, `aud` is an AES 256-bit base64 encoded field.  I'm going to be using a secret key in a wrapper method which will call `decrypt_base64_to_string(aud: &str)`.